# Cant update product in Magento

Tags: php, sql, magento, zend-framework

I am having some problems when I try and update a product. Lets say i want to add product to a new category, when i click save it just keeps loading, nothing happens.

Problems started when I enabled `flat_catalog`, when I tried to build table with `"Reindex all"`, server could not handle sql threads, so i needed to disable `flat_category` again.

In **error logs** i see `SQL timeout`. Any suggestions to what can be problem?

This is from log:

```
   exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait         timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' in        /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `catalog...', Array)
#5 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `catalog...', Array)
#6 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(632): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `catalog...', Array)
#7 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1357): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('catalog_product...', Array, '`entity_id`=309...')
#8 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1123): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_processSaveData(Array)
#9 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#10 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(728): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#11 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#12 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#13 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/index.php(111): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#17 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction' in /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `catalog...', Array)
#4 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `catalog...', Array)
#5 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(632): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `catalog...', Array)
#6 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1357): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('catalog_product...', Array, '`entity_id`=309...')
#7 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1123): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_processSaveData(Array)
#8 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product))
#9 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(728): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#10 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#11 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
#12 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/webshop.com/public_html/index.php(111): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

first clear out the `flat` tables by suing `DELETE FROM table;` then kick off the indexing outside magento via the shell

[Unix](http://turnkeye.com/blog/reindex-magento-database-linux-shell/)

[Windows](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/332176/)

if your still getting the error then it's a setting in your sql instance, alter the setting and restart the server for the change to take place then start again. you can change it back after since you just need to do that reindex